# The word 'bastardization' and its usage

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have difficulty understanding the word '*bastardization*' in this sentence I took from a vocabulary-builder app:

> The movie World War Z is a complete **bastardization** of the book
> with little more in common than zombies and a title.

Not only do I not understand the meaning of it, but also the usage of the word. By the way, the app gives the synonym 'corruption' and according to [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bastardization) (the fifth definition), it means:

> The creation of an inferior copy or version; corruption, degradation, or debasement.

It hasn't enlightened me about its meaning. If I make a correct guess, is it the same way to say, as if someone adapts the story of a film from a novel, but he changes the story drastically?

If so, can I use it like this:

> The Harry Potter franchise is an absolute bastardization of the original
> books!

Comment: The movie did not change the book. If something was bastardized, it was the movie. I believe the right phrasing should be "The movie World War Z is a complete bastard of the book".

Comment: That suggestion is completely unidiomatic for me, @yewgeniy: _Bastard_ is simply not used that way.

Comment: You'd have to say *the* Harry Potter franchise.  But otherwise yes, it's fine.

Comment: @ColinFine - familiar to me (UK locale) - Collins Dictionary ADJECTIVE If you refer to something as a bastardized form of something else, you mean that the first thing is similar to or copied from the second thing, but is of much poorer quality.
[formal, disapproval]. Cambridge Dictionary similar, with example _I  made a bastardized version of a seafood marinara using tinned tuna._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Truly gross. No, I shall not come to dinner. :) Anyway, re bastarized, yes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I was replying to Yewgeniy's suggestion of _The movie World War Z is a complete bastard of the book_.

Comment: @ColinFine - I agree absolutely  - you can't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Bastardization" means a corruption, a poor and distorted copy. The use of the term always indicates a quite negative judgement of the copy or adaptation.

The term is often used for some sort of transformation or derived work, such as a movie from a  book, or a modern version from a classic work. The derived work is said to be a bastardization of the original. The term is not used when the derived work is just different, it expresses a negative value judgement.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that would be the same. Bastard originally meant a child from outside of marriage. They wouldn't receive the inheritance of their parents.

Bastardized, means something that isn't a good representation of the original. It fails to inherit from the original and perhaps came from a tainted source.

Comment: Which does make it have uncomfortable implications (e.g. "people whose parents were not married are inferior").